# I'm getting errors concerning my template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently doing an assignment for course and it involves creating a template class. I have the template class set up and everything, but I'm getting errors that I can't seem to fix. I have tried various solutions and neither have worked so far, I have also done a reasonable amount of research and found no answers, precisely relevant to my scenario, concerning the problem although many others have asked.

Here is the code thus far...

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "Queue.h"
#include "MyException.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Stack;

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Stack<T>&);

template<class T>
class Stack
{
  public:
    Stack();
    Stack(const Stack<T>& other);
    void push(const T& el);
    T pop();
    T peek();
    bool isEmpty();

    friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Stack<T>&);

    Stack<T>& operator=(const Stack<T>& other);~Stack();

  private:
    class Node
    {
      public:
        Node(const T& data, Node* n = 0)
        {
            element = data;
            next = n;
        }

        T element;
        Node* next;
};

    Node* top;

};

#include "Stack.cpp"

#endif
```

that is the "Stack.h" and then there is

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{

}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& other)
{

}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& el)
{

}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{

}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::peek()
{

}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return false;
}
```

that is the "Stack.cpp".
I understand that the implementation being in a different file is not the generally accepted method, but unfortunately that is where the code needs to be. Now when I run this even without any real code, so to speak, i get the following errors.

```
3: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token
3: expected ';' before '<' token
9: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token
9: expected ';' before '<' token
17: expected init-declarator before '<' token
17: expected ';' before '<' token
23: expected init-declatator before '<' token
23: expected ';' before '<' token
```

and it goes on like that for each function up unto line 35.

Now, could it be my compiler? Could it be that I haven't finished all the functions and returned something yet?

Any help whatsoever would be largely appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is the *required* #include directive in your .cpp file?

Comment: You should include Stack.h in your cpp file, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with a template class it works the other way around. Including the .h in the .cpp makes it compile the functions circularly basically. the .cpp is included at the bottom of the .h

Comment: Normally what you call stack.cpp I name stack.inl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208028/significance-of-a-inl-file-in-c

Comment: Avoid to use `using namespace std;` in header.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compile Stack.cpp in a separate translation unit; it is already included in Stack.h.

`clang++ -c Stack.h -std=c++11`

works just fine.

Comment: What if you don't have c++11? I am working in Visual Studio 2005 just because, :P

Comment: You need a clang compiler. However, on windows i would prefer gcc over clang, since clang on windows is still pretty fresh. You can find one possible gcc build for windows on http://www.mingw.org.

Comment: But if I use gcc the command will work the same way? I will just have to change clang to gcc?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are suppose to include the .h file in your .cpp file. So remove the

```
#include "Stack.cpp"
```

That is at the bottom of your header file and add

```
#include "Stack.h"
```

to the top of your .cpp file.

Comment: I an not downvoting this answer however I believe a template class should not be implemented in a cpp file in almost all cases.

Comment: @drescherjm I have actually never worked with template classes. I have just tested his code in a blank project with the changes that me and Namfuak suggested and it builds fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file