# Legacy windows codebase can't include a <time.inl> file on vs2015, what/where is it?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have inherited a legacy Windows application at work, it has a file that `#include <time.inl>`.  It builds on the machines at work: windows 7, vs2013, but not on my home machine, windows 7, community vs2015.

I also come from a linux dev environment, so I'm not even sure what a `*.inl` file is.  Hopefully this is a simple question.

EDIT: okay I see this q: [Significance of a .inl file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208028/significance-of-a-inl-file-in-c)
which explains what it is, but still not sure how vs2013 compiles it fine and community vs2015 doesn't when the file does not exist in either place.

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/168947/

Comment: The silly original developers used a file that belongs to the implementation, and is compiler and version specific. Presumably it supports "time.h", so include that instead. There is a nice positive aspect about this, namely that now you KNOW that those developers had not the slightest understanding of what they were doing, so you don't need to waste time on trying to understand things: there's probably nothing to understand, just arbitrary results of blindly copying and modifying.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you have described the previous 'architect' exactly!